# Fedora Docker image doesn't have xargs

Tags: docker, dockerfile, fedora, xargs

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora:27

RUN xargs
```

When I run `docker build -t test .` I get the following output:

```
$ docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM fedora:27
 ---> 7a2e85963474
Step 2/2 : RUN xargs
 ---> Running in fbe9bfbedfe0
/bin/sh: xargs: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c xargs' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I expect Fedora to have `xargs` by default, but it does not appear to be available.  What else should I try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need `xargs`, then install `xargs`. Docker images are intentionally minimal; you are meant to customize them with the tools you need by using them as the base for building your own image.

```
FROM fedora:27

RUN yum -y install findutils
RUN xargs
```

If you're not sure which package provides a command you can also run `yum -y install /usr/bin/xargs`.

Comment: I had already tried that, I get the following error when I run the `yum` command: `No match for argument: xargs
Error: Unable to find a match
The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install xargs' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: Some of the images are so minimal, yum isn't present either.